# How to solve FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memor on Typescript 'npm run build'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, memory-management, v8

How to solve the: **FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0xa08900 node::Abort() [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.1/bin/node]**  when running `npm run build` on TypeScript project.

I have been trying the Fixes from my research here in Stackoverflow and other Forums but I am not winning. I updated from Node.js version 10 to version 12.18.1 but still, the problem persists. I tried to create a SWAP file but yet I didn't win. Previously the problem would go away by recreating a SWAP file. I am using Digital Ocean Ubuntu server 20.4. Please assist me to solve those issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to allow a larger heap size (which by default is computed automatically based on available system memory -- swap files don't count for that).

The flag you need for that is `--max-old-space-size` (with a value in megabytes), [apparently](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12238) one way of setting it is to run npm as follows:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4000 /usr/bin/npm run build
```

or you can use `NODE_OPTIONS` or `.npmrc` if you prefer.

If that doesn't help, or if you need more help, please provide some more information:

- how much memory does your server have?
- how much memory is being consumed at the point of the out-of-memory error?
- is there any way for someone else to reproduce the problem, or does it involve proprietary software? Can you create a public repro case?

> I updated from Node.js version 10 to version 12.18.1

Probably unrelated to your issue, but that's still a fairly old version. How about 12.20.0 (if it has to be the v12 line, which is in maintenance mode) or 14.15.1 (current "active LTS")?

> /root/.nvm/...

Why do you run node as root??!!
Don't ever run *anything* as root!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have been wondering why SWAP files are no longer working, now I see where you say this is based on available RAM on the system. I also inspected the RAM while Building, I saw it was exponentially going down from around 1900MB to 50MB available, surely the system stops it when it gets below that. Thank you yet more!

Answer (score 12):

Increase the node max memory size

```
// terminal
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096

// Windows
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096
```